# Starting GUI programs from WSL using AutoHotKey: how to tell cmd which $DISPLAY variable to use?

Tags: command-line, bash, cmd.exe, autohotkey, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have lately found the correct configuration for using Xming to get `gvim.exe` started from my WSL (Windows Subon Windows, and I wonder if I can automate the procedure. At the end of the day, I would like to **replicate** the following mapping that fires `gvim.exe` in WSL together with the parameter. (The short command to issue is `gvim +SLoad`

```
#k::
    ShellRun("C:\vim\vim80\gvim.exe", "+SLoad", "", "", 3)
return
```

### Step 1: get things to work with `cmd.exe`

According to [the guide to invoke wsl](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/11/28/a-guide-to-invoking-wsl/), I should be able to start GUI programs normally, by feeding in the `-c` flag as follows:

```
bash -c gvim
# Or, wsl does not need the flag, thus:
wsl gvim
```

Yet, per the two commands, I get similar error as if I did not set up the `$DISPLAY` varaible when I was with the WSL comamnd-line.

[image]

### Step 2: reviewing the correct configuration from WSL

Depending on where the GUI program is fired, one needs to drop the following line to the correct configuration file. For the default `bash` shell, put it in `~/.bashrc`. For Fish shell, put it in `~/.config/fish/config.fish`.

```
# XMing config
export DISPLAY=:0
```

The value of the `$DISPLAY` variable is set according to how Xming specifies its own starting parameters. Popping open one that got added to the Start Menu reveals the settings: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Xming\Xming.exe" :0 -clipboard -multiwindow`.

## Question: how may I set up the environmental variables for cmd?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17405182/5164855) shows how to create a command file which runs each time `cmd` is started, before any command is executed or prompted for, allowing you to preset any environment variables, among other things.

Comment: Try using `bash -c "DISPLAY=:0 gvim"`.

Comment: @harrymc, Amazing! the flag worked great. Could you submit an answer? Let me know if you want me to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure the environment variable is truly passed to the program, use:

```
bash -c "DISPLAY=:0 gvim"
```

The shell syntax `VARIABLE=VALUE COMMAND` sets the environment variable VARIABLE
for the duration of the specified command only. It is roughly equivalent to
`(export VARIABLE=VALUE; exec COMMAND)`.

Displays are numbered from 0, so `:0` is the first local display that was started.

Like all environment variables, DISPLAY is inherited from parent process to
child process. However, when started from WSL, there are apparently some glitches.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am appending your post with a working version of AHK script, that summons WSL-driven Gvim.